# What is the correct design pattern for using Wrappers as Adapters in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

Let say we have some Bean (which is POJO)

```
public class Bean {
}
```

And we have BeanWrapper which is a wrapper over Bean and represents DTO for the Bean class. Also supports adapter to and from Bean.

```
public class BeanWrapper {
    public Bean toBean() {}

    public static BeanWrapper fromBean(Bean bean) {}
}
```

The question is on the method `fromBean`.
What should be the correct design pattern for this method - should it be static method?

In other words what is better:

```
BeanWrapper wrapper = BeanWrapper.fromBean(bean);
```

Or just non-static method and use it like following:

```
BeanWrapper wrapper = new BeanWrapper().populateBean(bean);
```

Edit from comments:
Or go with a constructor:

```
BeanWrapper wrapper = new BeanWrapper(Bean bean);
```

Which one is better and preferred way over other? And why is it like that?

Comment: This question is primarily opinion-based. An alternative you have not consider is to use a constructor that takes the bean. Then there is no need for a separate `populateBean` method, and the choice between a static method or a constructor is largely a matter of taste.

Comment: I agree, this question is primarily opinion-based. For example, you could also use a framework that dictates the pattern. Here's one as an example: http://mapstruct.org/

Answer (score 1):

That depends - so opinion based. If you are using CDI (Content Dependency Injection) it might be better to use the first option by first injecting the wrapper and refrain from making the methods static. This is in a CDI environment preferable as it stays closer to the OO paradigm.

My opinion is to only use public static methods only when absolutely necessary. e.g. factory methods.

For the rest all of the options are a matter of what you decide with your team. Be consistent though.

Why I think static methods are evil (in most cases):

- OO principles like polymorphism are just thrown away with static methods.
- A static method indicates a method that does not know where it belongs. OO promotes the "Who is responsible" and every method should belong to something
- Testability is a problem. Every piece of code that calls a static method needs to test this static method in its entirety as the compiler "copies" that static method as-is into the calling method. This makes for unmaintainable tests.
- They can be viewed as kinda global methods / procedures. So the class it is written in is actually only there for its name not for its state or responsibility
- Code becomes more complex as it is difficult to say what it is for and why it should be used and in what context. Misuse is easy.

As Java is an OO language it is good practice to use it in that context. With that in mind IMHO it is only good to use public static methods in these cases:

- Factory methods
- Unit tests